# Compiling NPM gives elifecycle 3221225725

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to run a production on npm. I'm getting the following errors. I have attached the log and error report from npm. I'm running windows 10 and tried different nodejs versions. Perhaps anybody knows what is causing this error.

```
PS C:\Users\\Desktop\server> npm run production
Debugger attached.

> @ production C:\Users\\Desktop\server
> cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

Debugger attached.
Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 3221225725
npm ERR! @ production: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 3221225725
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ production script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-25T21_06_27_383Z-debug.log
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
PS C:\Users\\Desktop\server>
```

The complete log is:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'production'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.12
3 info using node@v12.22.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'preproduction', 'production', 'postproduction' ]
5 info lifecycle @~preproduction: @
6 info lifecycle @~production: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~production: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~production: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\\Desktop\server\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle @~production: CWD: C:\Users\\Desktop\server
10 silly lifecycle @~production: Args: [
10 silly lifecycle   '/d /s /c',
10 silly lifecycle   'cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'
10 silly lifecycle ]
11 silly lifecycle @~production: Returned: code: 3221225725  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~production: Failed to exec production script
13 verbose stack Error: @ production: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 3221225725
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1022:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\\Desktop\server
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "production"
18 verbose node v12.22.1
19 verbose npm  v6.14.12
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 3221225725
22 error @ production: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
22 error Exit status 3221225725
23 error Failed at the @ production script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 3221225725, true ]
```

Without luck I tried:

rm node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm cache clear --force
npm install

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node npm run watch Exit status 3221225725](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54177255/node-npm-run-watch-exit-status-3221225725)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That topic I've also read and  I don't have an .env file so unfortunately it didn't help me :-(.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! I made progress. It's fixed with installing another version of laravel-mix. I ran the next command, and now it's building fine.

```
npm i laravel-mix@0.11.4
```